# What change can I make to this JS code to keep animation but hide elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the JavaScript code where when the user clicks on a new tab the contents on that page have a fade out effect by setting the opacity to 0. However the flaw is that all links from other pages are still clickable because it is only the opacity that has changed. What edit can I make to this code to keep the animation but hide the page content after the animation. (The same animation is when the page loads, but the opacity changes to 1.)

Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

/* How to Handle Hashtags */
jQuery(window).hashchange(function(){
    var hash = location.hash;
    jQuery('a[href='+hash+']').trigger('click');
});

/* Main Navigation Clicks */
jQuery('.main-nav ul li a').click(function() {
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(1);

    if ( !jQuery('section.content.show, section#' + link).is(':animated') ) {
        jQuery('.main-nav ul li a').removeClass('active'); //remove active
        jQuery('section.content.show').addClass('show').animate({'opacity' : 0}, {queue: false, duration: 1000,
            complete: function() {
                jQuery('a[href="#'+link+'"]').addClass('active'); // add active
                jQuery('section#' + link).addClass('show').animate({'opacity' : 1}, {queue: false, duration: 1000});    
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

Can you please re-paste the code with the edits as I am not the best at JS.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your css and html? It's hard to diagnosis this, but you could use `.fadeOut()` or `.animate({"display":"none"})`. I'm not sure if this is what you need, you'll have to post the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the `display` property to `none` in the callback (or just call `hide()`):

```
complete: function() {
    jQuery(this).hide();
    jQuery('a[href="#'+link+'"]').addClass('active'); // add active
    jQuery('section#' + link).addClass('show').animate({'opacity' : 1}, {queue: false, duration: 1000});
}
```

Obviously you then have to take care to show the elements back again before animating them back in. ;-)